# How can I use grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-contrib-coffee to compile CoffeeScript only as needed?

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-coffee

I'd like to run coffee lint and coffee compile on only the single file that I'm saving. There are hundreds of CoffeeScript files in my project, and compiling all of them takes too much time.

Here's my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->

  grunt.initConfig

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON 'package.json'

    coffee:
      all:
        expand: true
        bare: true
        cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
        src: '**/*.coffee'
        dest: 'public/js/compiled'
        ext: '.js'

    coffeelint:
      all: ['src/coffeescript/**/*.coffee']

    watch:
      coffeescript:
        files: ['src/**/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffeelint', 'coffee']
        options:
          spawn: false

  grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath) ->
    grunt.config(['coffeelint', 'all'], filepath)
    grunt.config(['coffee', 'all'], filepath)

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-coffeelint'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'

  grunt.registerTask 'default', ['coffeelint', 'coffee', 'watch']
```

The coffeelint task runs successfully only on the changed file.

The coffee compilation doesn't produce any JS files, even though grunt says it runs.

Here's the output after saving a single coffee file:

```
OK
>> File "src/coffeescript/app.coffee" changed.


Running "coffeelint:all" (coffeelint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "coffee:all" (coffee) task

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.009s at Sat Feb 01 2014 13:10:07 GMT-0600 (CST) - Waiting...
```

What's wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

Here's a working example:

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->

  fs = require 'fs'
  isModified = (filepath) ->
    now = new Date()
    modified =  fs.statSync(filepath).mtime
    return (now - modified) < 10000

  grunt.initConfig

    coffee:
      options:
        sourceMap: true
        bare: true
        force: true # needs to be added to the plugin
      all:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
        src: '**/*.coffee'
        dest: 'public/js/compiled'
        ext: '.js'
      modified:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
        src: '**/*.coffee'
        dest: 'public/js/compiled'
        ext: '.js'
        filter: isModified

    coffeelint:
      options:
        force: true
      all:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
        src: '**/*.coffee'
      modified:
        expand: true
        cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
        src: '**/*.coffee'
        filter: isModified

    watch:
      coffeescript:
        files: ['src/**/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['coffeelint:modified', 'coffee:modified']

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-coffeelint'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'

  grunt.registerTask 'default', ['coffeelint:all', 'coffee:all', 'watch']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add something like this to your c task

```
 coffee:
  all:
    filter: (filepath) ->
        fs = require('fs')
        now = new Date()
        modified =  fs.statSync(filepath).mtime
        return (now - modified) < 10000 # or another difference in millyseconds
```

Read more in [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) to only compile files when the source is newer than its compiled output.

Install it with:

```
npm install grunt-newer --save-dev
```

Then change your coffeescript task a bit. If you go to section on "Building the files object dynamically" in the [Grunt.js docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) you'll see that you need to hold the information related to file location and location of compiled output in a `files` array for the task to execute correctly.

Additional options, like `bare: true`, can then be specified with an options object.

So for your `coffee` task, do this instead:

```
   coffee:
      all:
        files: [{
          expand: true
          cwd: 'src/coffeescript/'
          src: '**/*.coffee'
          dest: 'public/js/compiled'
          ext: '.js'
        }]
        options:
          bare: true
          spawn: false
```

then use newer in your watch task like so:

```
    watch:
      coffeescript:
        files: ['src/**/*.coffee']
        tasks: ['newer:coffeelint:all', 'newer:coffee:all']
        options:
          spawn: false
```

Newer will then only compile files that are more recent than their compiled versions.

Comment: This does only compile the coffee files that have changed, but it run coffee lint on ALL coffee files :-(

Comment: Yes. I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

#### First:

Grunt produces changed file path as `src/coffeescript/some_file.coffee`, but in your `coffee` task you have defined `cwd` as `src/coffeescript`.

So the coffee task is actually expecting only `some_file.coffee` but it is getting `src/coffeescript/some_file.coffee`, and then expanding it to `src/coffeescript/src/coffeescript/some_file.coffee` O_o

Your `coffeelint` task doesn't have any `cwd` so it runs successfully with the full file path.

Adjust the file path accordingly, or remove the `cwd` from the coffee configuration.

```
grunt.config(['coffee', 'all'], filepath.replace("src/coffeescript", ""))
```

#### Second:

This one is minor, and may not be required, but watch out for this as well.

```
grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath) ->
  grunt.config(['coffeelint', 'all'], filepath)
  grunt.config(['coffee', 'all'], filepath)
  ^^^^^^^ You might have to change above line to:
  grunt.config(['coffee', 'all', 'src'], filepath)
```

In your coffeelint task, sources are directly set under `all`. But in your `coffee` task, sources are set under `all -> src`. Reflecting the same might also be useful.

EDIT: Minor addendum

Comment: First:

    >> File "src/coffeescript/app.coffee" changed.


    Running "coffeelint:files" (coffeelint) task
    >> 1 file lint free.

    Running "coffee:files" (coffee) task
    Warning: Unable to read "undefined" file (Error code: ENOENT).

Comment: Second: no JavaScript files are created.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an arbitrary duration threshold, you could store each modification time in a map:

```
fs = require 'fs'
mtimes = {}
isModified = (filepath) ->
    mtime = fs.statSync(filepath).mtime
    if mtimes[filepath]?
        return mtimes[filepath] < mtime
    else
        mtimes[filepath] = mtime
        return yes
```

It's too bad though that grunt does not provide the destination file path as a second argument to the filter function. This would enable a simple check to see if the generated file exists and is older than the source… [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) does that out of the box…